# Run time too long (possible loop leak), C

Tags: c, arrays

Ok me and my friend have been working on this task from school where we are to sort one array by the order of another array. We have found a working solution that we can use. The problem is that when we are to hand in the work to auto correction, they don't accept it because of time limit exceeded. So we've made many optimizations by taking away as many loops as possible. Still it has not been enough. I've tried adding a count++ to see if there is a loop running many times. What I found was that the loop after the bubble sorting could be the leak. Removing j=0 would remove the time limit exceeded, but would instead give a wrong answer according to the auto correction.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5000

int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, n=0, tmp=0, tmp1 = 0;
    int list1[MAXSIZE],list2[MAXSIZE], list11[MAXSIZE];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n!=0)
      {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&list1[i]);
            list11[i]=list1[i]; 
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&list2[i]);
        }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                if (list11[j] > list11[i]) 
                {
                    tmp = list11[i]; 
                    list11[i] = list11[j]; 
                    list11[j] = tmp; 
                }
                tmp1=0;     
                if (list2[j] > list2[i]) 
                {
                    tmp1 = list2[i]; 
                    list2[i] = list2[j]; 
                    list2[j] = tmp1; 
                }
            }   
       }
       //Possible leak
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (list1[i]==list11[j])
            {
                list1[i]=list2[j];
                j=0;
            }
        }
       }
       printf("\n");
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
        printf("%d\n",list1[i]);
       }
       scanf("%d", &n);
       if(n == 0)
        break;
       else
        printf("\n");
    } 
  return 0;
}
```

Could there be a "leak" of some sort? Some sort of endless loop or a loop taking a lot of time when numbers are great? This error happens when the code takes more than one second to perform.

Comment: `while (n!=0)` ??? Sure it is the cause of an endless loop...

Comment: it doesn't look like you ever dynamically allocate memory, which would make a leak impossible

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès He scans into `n` each iteration, near the end

Comment: The loop is to continue for multiple runs untill the next "n" is 0. Thats why the while(n!=0). Forgot to add that part

Comment: @rtpax Oh I see, his formating is to bad and I didn't correctly interpret the code.

Comment: [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) happens when a program manages it's allocated memory (it's called dynamic allocation). You just allocate 15000 `int`'s in your program, but the allocation is done by OS, not by your program. The only possibility for a leak is inside `scanf` and `printf` function, assuming those are written correctly, there is no possibility of memory leak in your program. Is `n` lower then `MAX_SIZE`?

Comment: Yes 1 ≤ n  ≤ 5000. So what I believe to be the problem is that there is a loop going too many times

Answer (score 2):

Think twice.

```
if (list1[i]==list11[j])
   {
     list1[i]=list2[j];
     j=0;
   }
```

You may reset `j=0` endlessly, because the condition may always be true, if `list1[i]` equals to `list11[j]` equals to `list2[j]`...

Comment: How would I solve this? I have tried removing the j=0 part as I too believe thats the leak. But when I remove j=0 the auto correction tells me I get the wrong answer.

Comment: In fact I didn't analyze your algorithm, I just have a look at what could cause then endless loop. What is the purpose of these two loops? That is not clear to me.

Comment: So since I have sorted list11 and list2 in the bubble sorts above. I now want the list2s values in the order of list1. So what these loops are made to do is to sort list2 by the order of list1. And since list11 is the sorted copy of list1 aswell as list2 is sorted I use that to write over list1. Im trying my best to explain.

Comment: So lets say we first type 4. That makes n = 4. Now the first 4 numbers we type will go to list1. The 4 after that go to list2. We type 1 2 3 4 9 8 7 6. The order of list1 is smallest to biggest number. Now the numbers of list2 are to be sorted by that order. That would be 6 7 8 9. This is what the input and output would look like:

4
1
2
3
4
9
8
7
6

6
7
8
9
With only one number per row

Comment: Another example would be n=3. First 3 numbers (list1) 1 3 2. Last 3 numbers (list2) 7 8 9. The output would be 7 9 8.

Comment: I see (I think) so you just need one loop : `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) list11[i] = list2[list1[i]-1];` The result should be in list11 as list1 is your "order".

Comment: Hm, it seems to work for some cases but prints a "0" on a extra row. But it doesn't work for all test cases. When I tried the combination of n = 4. First 4 numbers: 9 61 62 30. Last 4 numbers: 55 73 10 6. All it printed was 5 zeros, 4 + the one extra mentioned at the beginning. When I tried this I changed the printf at the end to print list11 instead of list1

Comment: @user10445316 Of course you didn't clearly specified what list1 may contains! Always clearly specify what you want...